# How to make icons from FontAwesome with same width

Tags: html, css, sass, icons, font-awesome

I have few blocks with icons:

```
     <div class="contacts__icon">
          <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>                    
     </div>
     <div class="contacts__icon">
          <i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i>                    
     </div>
```

For them I have next styling:

```
        .contacts__icon{
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: #269f58;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: #fff;
            i{
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        }
```

The block supposed to be round with the same size, but somehow icons have a different width, I get ellipse and circle. how to make them the same size?
Since its icons from FontAwesone, i tried to use fa-fw attribute: `<i class="fa-fw fas fa-map-marker"></i>`, but that made the icon be placed not in centre but with some shift, which is also not pleasable

Answer (score 0):

You can add a width and height to `.contacts__icon` and then add padding to the icons. I specified different rules for both icons as the marker looked a little skewed to the left when using the same rule as the phone. I converted your sass to css in order to give an example, but the sass would be:

```
.contacts__icon {
 background-color: #269f58;
 border-radius: 50%;
 color: #fff;
 width: 45px;
 height: 45px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 i[class="fas fa-phone"] {
   padding-left: 12px;
   padding-top: 12px;
   font-size: 20px;
 }
 i[class="fas fa-map-marker"] {
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-top: 12px;
 font-size: 20px;
 }
}
```

```css
.contacts__icon {
  background-color: #269f58;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contacts__icon i[class="fas fa-phone"] {
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.contacts__icon i[class="fas fa-map-marker"] {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="contacts__icon">
          <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>                 
     </div>
<div class="contacts__icon">
          <i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i>                    
     </div>
```